# How to write the regex to capture alphanumeric value between square brackets?

Tags: shell, ksh

Please help in writing the regular expression for below line in bash.
There are muliple lines like this in my file, and I want to only capture the below values from the file. How can I do so?

value to be extracted -

```
Y324256
vmigha3
idea
```

Note - The value to be extracted is always alphanumeric. Square brackets on the left and right side will always have numeric values which I don't want to extract.

File looks like this-

```
2021-05-13 15:35:31,804 [16] [Y324256] [341745] DEBUG Server - End Webservice method GetProcessStatus
2021-05-13 15:35:32,587 [11] [vmigha3] [341749] DEBUG Domain - Reading user permissions from the database
2022-03-03 09:08:10,699 [31] [idea] [80387] INFO Server - Begin Webservice call
2022-04-06 01:18:33,822 [MonitorThread] INFO  - Reading user permissions from the database
2022-04-06 01:18:33,845 [None] DEBUG -Begin Webservice call
```

**code**

```
grep -oP '\[\K\d*[A-Za-z][\dA-Za-z]*(?=])' file > output_file
```

But this gives me below result -

```
Y324256
vmigha3
idea
MonitorThread
None
```

I am wondering if this can be done by first finding the lines which begins with **2022-04-06 01:18:33,845** this date format , then capture the 4th record.

Comment: will the desired data always be in the 2nd set of square brackets

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes the desired data will be in the second set of square brackets. I've updated the post with my code

Comment: based on the latest data update it appears you only want the data from the 2nd set of brackets *if* there are (at least) 3 sets of brackets; in the case of lines with a single set of brackets we ignore that line; correct?

Comment: the last line of the description about `finding the lines which begins with 2022-04-06 01:18:33,845 ... capture the 4th record` ... doesn't make sense with regards to the rest of the question (eg, has nothing to do with square brackets); are you trying to describe a 2nd set of criteria, or shoudl this last line of the description be removed from the question?

Answer (score 3):

Assumptions/Understandings:

- if there are 3x sets of `[...]` in the line then print the contents of the 2nd `[...]`
- otherwise skip the line

One `awk` idea using dual field delimiters of `]` and `[` (and no need for a regex):

```
$ awk -F'[][]' 'NF>6 {print $4}' file
Y324256
vmigha3
idea
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be grep? I mean:

```
cut -d[ -f3 file | cut -d] -f1
```

If it has to be, then just match the brackets.

```
grep -oP '^[^[]*\[[^[]*\[\K[^]]*'
```